# Export to excel in MVC application returns error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to export some data in MVC application. I keep getting an error, which is very strange - I can't resolve that error from Fiddler.

Here is java script which calls controller action:

```
var exportXLSDeadlinesParent = function () {
        if ($('#hiddenParentCount').val() > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '../../Administration/UserManagement/exportUserProp',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'typeToExport=PARENT',                
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (xhr, err) {
                    alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                    alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

And here is action controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public virtual void exportUserProp(string typeToExport, string validFrom = null)
        {
            var query = ModelPropSessions:           

            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", "historyData", typeToExport));

                ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ID user";
                ws.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Agent number";
                ws.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Deadline type";                             

                for (int z = 0; z < query.Count(); z++)
                {                    
                    ws.Cells[z + 2, 1].Value = query[z].USERID;                    
                    ws.Cells[z + 2, 2].Value = query[z].USER_INT_NUM;                   
                    ws.Cells[z + 2, 3].Value = query[z].DESC;                    
                }

                string myFile = "FileToExport";

                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + myFile);
                Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
                Response.End();
            }            
        }
```

In debugger everything is cool - call comes to server side and creates excel file. But, on the client side I am receiving an error:

readyState = 4
status = OK

and for the responseText I receive some characters which I can not read. It seems that this is excel file, which should be saved. Why I can't save it 
and keep getting an error response ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ? Can't send `content-disposition attachment` in ajax

Comment: Monkeying around with the `Response` is unnecessary in MVC, return a `FileResult` instead using `return File()`; an overload of that will take a byte array.

Comment: I've tried to return FileResult with no success. Same thing. It seems like response comes back, but the result is not shown as excel file to be saved.